# Entity Framework Child Delete - but still I can see the row in parent

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern

I've a project using EF and repository pattern.
I have the old same relation --> 1 to many....
I can delete the child row from parent. In DB is completely deleted.

But still I see the reference to this object in parent.

I can't really figure it out...

I'm novice with EF

Thanks

JDIBO

Comment: Show us your repository code that will delete the Child.

Comment: If you just delete the child object itself and call `context.SaveChanges()` it will get deleted form the database, but the parent will still have it in its collection of child objects until you remove it explicitly or create a new instance of the context.

Comment: .......What a mess...if I run the same code in the mvc application I've no problem...I don't see the deleted ones...but If i run from a console application I get this behaviour....

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're not throwing away your DbContext after you've done SaveChanges.  DbContextes represent units of work, and should be destoried as soon as you are done with them.  Create a new DbContext to query the data after your update.